# Migrate products, orders, users, attributes, and options from Ubercart 2 to Ubercart 3

Tags: 7, migrations, ubercart

I am working on a new Drupal 7 site to replace a Drupal 6 site that was badly compromised. I have built the D7 site from scratch, and I now need to migrate the Ubercart products, orders, attributes, and options (as well as the users) from the D6 site to the D7 site. I found [this page](https://drupal.org/node/850180), but it appears to only be for migrating into Ubercart 2/D6. Can anyone here shed some light on how I can make this migration work?

One of the things I tried was exporting the individual database tables from the D6 site and importing them into the D7 site's database. It seems to have worked for the Atributes and options, but unfortunately this did not work for the products/nodes... when I view the Content listing page in the D7 admin, it shows the page at the bottom of the screen but it says I have "No content available".

Thanks!

Comment: I'm affraid that if this question couldn't be answered good enough for you on ubercart.org ([see](http://www.ubercart.org/forum/support/31357/upgrade_version_2_version_3_d6_d7)) it can't be answered here too. There they say "Probably depends on what UC modules you have installed and if they have a D7/UC version." so please at least provide that information.

Comment: @Mołot  That thread is actually a slightly different situation.  I don't see a problem with this question.